# How to Check an UIImageView Present in position of a view in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I have a imageview in a specific position , i know the position but i want to check if there is an imageview in that position.

please help me out to solve

Answer (score 3):

Here is a helper method to check if two rects overlap:

```
-(BOOL) rect:(CGRect)rect overlap:(CGRect)anotherRect
{
    BOOL xOverlap = ((rect.origin.x >= anotherRect.origin.x) && (rect.origin.x <= anotherRect.origin.x + anotherRect.size.width)) ||
                    ((anotherRect.origin.x >= rect.origin.x) && (anotherRect.origin.x <= rect.origin.x + rect.size.width));

    BOOL yOverlap = ((rect.origin.y >= anotherRect.origin.y) && (rect.origin.y <= anotherRect.origin.y + anotherRect.size.height)) ||
                    ((anotherRect.origin.y >= rect.origin.y) && (anotherRect.origin.y <= rect.origin.y + rect.size.height));

    return xOverlap && yOverlap;
}
```

Usage:
You can iterate though all subviews of a view and check if the frame of your view overlaps another view's frame. Suppose you have a property myView then:

```
for(UIView *v in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if(v == self.myView) //skip the same view
            continue;

        if([self rect:self.myView.frame overlap:v.frame])
        {
            //Do something...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you get the array of all your views inside your main view:

```
NSArray *subviews = [view subviews];
```

Then, for every view, you can check the frame of every view:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < [subviews count]; i++){
    CGRect frame = [subviews objectAtIndex:i].frame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate through the subviews of the superview of that UIImageView in a for loop. And compare the position of each view to that specific UIImageView's position.

But this sounds bad to me. Maybe if you can tell more about the issue, we can help better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach as well:

Since you have said you have position of the ImageView then save this in some CGRect variable.Try this

```
UIImageView *yourImgView = (UIImageView *)[view subviews];
```

This will return your imageView . Then you can check its frame with earlier saved position or its visibility depending on your need.